# Hide login activity

Tags: android

I have LoginActivity which checks SharedPreferences for login details then it redirects to HomeActivity and other activities after that. I have put Menu item Sign Out on each of this activities and used this code on sign out button.

```
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
```

How to hide the Login activity, so that when user press back button from home screen it'll close the app.

Like when I open app it shows Home screen and when I press back button normally it should close the app. But in my case it takes me to the Login screen which is the first screen checking user credentials.

I cannot end the Login activity, otherwise that solution doesn't work.

I'm a new to Android. Please suggest something to solve this problem.

Comment: use android:noHistory="true" in menifest for login activity.

Comment: I tried that, but it removes activity from stack.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you should try this on your home Activity's back key function:

```
onBackpress(){
 Intent intent = new Intent(mContext, LoginActivity.class);
 intent.putExtra("FLAG", 0);
 intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP); 
 intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP); 
 startActivity(intent);
}
```

and on your LoginActivity just do:

```
 onNewIntent(Intent intent){
   int i = intent.getIntExtra("FLAG", 0);

   if(i == 0) 
      finish();

 }
```

remember launchMode for activity in menifest should be singleTop.

Comment: Shows error "The method putIntExtra(String, int) is undefined for the type Intent" on  putIntExtra.
and "getData cannot be resolved or is not a field" on getData.

Comment: thanks man! works perfect. Can you briefly explain me what we've done?

Comment: SINGLE_TOP start activity from back stack but using this intent you invoke onNewIntent() of starting activity, in which it just call finish();

Comment: When I change the Orientation of the screen, the solution does not work. Any idea how to solve that problem?

Comment: use android:configChanges="orientation", this will not recreate your activity.

Comment: I write that line in Login actvity manifest file, but the problem remain as it is.

Comment: do you check it in real device??

Comment: No, I'm checking it in emulator. Does it differ from a device?

Answer (score 4):

Override the [Activity.onBackPressed()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onBackPressed%28%29) method and then send the application home via an Intent.

From the SDK:

An intent with the following categories will allow you to go home.

> ACTION_MAIN with category CATEGORY_HOME -- Launch the home screen.

Comment: I Override onBackPressed in Home activity. but, what code I write inside the fuction to close the app.

Comment: You dont kill your app, the ActivityManager will do that for you, just send an Intent home.

Comment: My app asks for username and password for first time and after that it directly opens home page. But, when I press back button it takes to login activity. So at back button from home activity i want to close the app (not forcefully kill the app).

Comment: I write action.MAIN and category.HOME in <intent-filter> tag in Manifest file. but it has no effect.

Comment: you're doing it wrong, it has **NOTHING** to do with your manifest. I said create an Intent with those characteristics. Learn your documentation...

Comment: Sorry I'm new in Android. Thanks for help.
I write ACTION_MAIN and CATEGORY_HOME in onBackPressed() and it worked. 
but, next time I open app it starts with home screen.

Answer (score 1):

You can override the back button keypress event and have it close the app when pressed.